# What is the lifecycle of tabs, when switching between Tabs in TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I have five tabs in Tablayout with fragments. I have a Floating button at the Bottom right corner of the first Tab. when I click the FAB button, it inflates a small CardView(Initially Cardview was set to INVISIBLE), and when I click FAB button again, Cardview goes to invisible state. (To achieve that, I have used 'flags' true and false).

Now, my requirement is--- Suppose, I am in first Tab. And I clicked the FAB button, in return, it inflated Cardview. Without clicking the FAB button again(Cardview is in VISIBLE state) I went to second Tab. Then, I moved to First Tab from the second Tab. but, still the Cardview stays VISIBLE state.

I want to make the Cardview INVISIBLE when I move to other Tabs and come back.

please tell me how to achieve that functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the lifecycle of tabs, when switching between Tabs in TabLayout

Kindly go through this [Answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576198/android-tab-fragment-not-calling-oncreateview-switching-from-tab2-to-tab1/28576429#28576429) to understand what happens when you switch the tabs.

> I want to make the Cardview INVISIBLE when I move to other Tabs and
> come back.

You can utilize `setOnTabSelectedListener` of `TabLayout`

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
  new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        super.onTabSelected(tab);
        // Do your login here.. according to tab positon
    }
});
```

Comment: Should I write this in Fragment or hosting Activity..??

Comment: An activity that hosts `viewpager` and `tabLayout`

Comment: It says, setOnTabSelectedListener is deprecated.

Comment: Use `addOnTabSelectedListener`.

Comment: I am quite new to programming. would you tell me what to write in that Listener to make Cardview Invisible when I move between Tabs

Comment: Okay. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587584/call-tabbed-fragment-method-from-activity) will help. What you have to do is.. find current fragment of that specific tab position and access fragment methods which hide your `carView`

Comment: The link is not working anymore.